# Get mutual friend by 2 other id (someone between someone) Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I use Facebook PHP SDK and I'm new with Facebook API. It's hard for me to understand FB API documentation.

I try to make reputation system based on this journal [Reputation system based on seller-buyer closeness degree for e-commerce](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=7013178)

In this system, I need to get mutual friends between 2 other id to count reputation point. unfortunately I only find doc how to get mutual friends between **me and someone id**, not mutual friends between **someone and someone id**.
So, this is my scenario:

- I logged in to system with facebook login, and my id is **1111**.
- Some store called "XXX Store" his id is **2222**.
- other people, his id is **3333**.

I can get mutual friends between **Me(1111) and XXX Store (2222)** with this code
developers.facebook.com/docs/grap-api/reference/v2.7/user.context/mutual_friends

```
$accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
try {   
    $response = $fb->get('/2222?fields=context.fields%28mutual_friends%29', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
$graphEdge = $graphNode["context"]["mutual_friends"];
echo "Mutual Friends : ",$graphEdge->getTotalCount();
```

but, how to get mutual friends between **XXX Store(2222) and Someone(3333)** when the one who logged in with FB api is **Me(1111)**?

Also I need to get total friend of XXX Store and someone. with this example
developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/ I only get **Me** friends. When I use someone id I don't get the result.
but I can trick this problem, when user logged in, the system store his/her total_friends in database.

Please help me, thanks.